# how to obtain the distribution of random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions

If we have two independent random variables modeled as triangular distribution centered around a mean in the interval (mean - a, mean + a). 'a' is finite value. Then discretized them at fixed sub-intervals. what will be the distribution of their max?

Comment: Formula (2) neglects the possibility that $X=Y=k$ and therefore is incorrect.  At the end you appear to confuse the *support* of a discrete distribution with a "sample size."  Samples aren't involved in any manner in these purely mathematical statements about properties of distributions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on sample size and in what cases the output pdf will be of size m+n?

Comment: I cannot elaborate on sample size because, as I stated, this question has nothing to do with sampling.  Your reference refers to "sample spaces:" these, by definition, are the sets of values the variables can attain.  Generally, when $X$ can take on $m$ values and $Y$ can take on $n$ values, $\max(X,Y)$ (which must be among these values) cannot have any more than $m+n-1$ possible values. It can have fewer when there are overlaps among the values attained by $X$ and $Y.$

Comment: @whuber I have a question about the number of samples multiplications during the maximum. Could you please explain to me how many multiplications are required to obtain the max distribution? if X and Y both has n samples, n*n multiplications needed to calculate Z samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be answered by considering the question: "in what ways can the $k$ be the maximum of these two random variables?"

Case 1: $X < k$ and $Y = k$. This happens with probability $P(X<k)P(Y=k)$, since the random variables are independent. This is indeed the first summand in $(1)$.

Case 2: $Y <k$ and $X=k$. Similarly, this happens with probability $P(Y<k)P(X=k)$. This is the second summand.

Case 3: It can also be the case (since the transformed distributions are discrete) that $Y=k$ and $X=k$. This happens with probability $P(Y=k)P(X=k)$. This is where the third summand comes into play, and there you have formula $(1)$.

In case the variables had been continuous, then the relevant formula would have been (with appropriate modifications) $(2)$, as case three happens with probability measure $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

I think you have a good start on this (+1), but it seems some of the counts in your PDF for $Z$ are
a little off. I can't replicate them in a simple
simulation in R.

```
set.seed(705) # for reproducibility
p = c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1)  # proportions 
x = sample(1:7, 10^7, rep=T, prob=p)
y = sample(2:8, 10^7, rep=T, prob=p)
z = pmax(x,y)

head(cbind(x, y, z)) # first 6 of ten million
     x y z
[1,] 6 5 6
[2,] 6 4 6
[3,] 6 5 6
[4,] 7 3 7
[5,] 1 4 4
[6,] 2 4 4

round(table(z)/10^7, 4)  # tabulated probabilities
z
     2      3      4      5      6      7      8 
0.0117 0.0587 0.1642 0.2734 0.2539 0.1755 0.0624
```

Your PDF is as follows:

```
pdf = c(7,27,42,78,79,50,16)
pdf = pdf/sum(pdf)
sum(pdf)
[1] 1
round(pdf, 4)
[1] 0.0234 0.0903 0.1405 0.2609 0.2642 0.1672 0.0535
```

Graph: Simulated values are heights of bars. Your PDF values are shown by (centers of) red circles.

```
plot(table(z)/10^7, ylab="Probability", xlab="z")
 abline(h = 0, col="green2")
 points(2:8, pdf, col="red")
```

[image]

Ten million iterations should give three place accuracy,
which is better than the resolution of the graph. So clear discrepancies in the graph probably represent actual
errors.

It seems especially easy to compute the exact probability $P(Z = 2) = 3/256 =   
0.0117,$ which agrees with the simulation, but not with
your $0.0234.$

I don't know if this is a source of numerical error
because I haven't checked all your arithmetic, but
it seems to me your formula
$P(X<k) = \sum_{t = -\infty}^k P(X=t)$ is not correct.

I hope some of this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i took the "incorrect formula" from the paper. i think the source of error is that we should not calculate p(x=k). we have to sum up the probabilities of all samples before k. (x < k) not (x<= k).

Comment: I just have one more question if we have two discretized distributions each contains say 20 samples. How many multiplications are required to obtain the max distribution?  is it 20*20?

Comment: I usually use a million iterations, which gives about three place accuracy. Here I used 10 million because not many variables were involved. 100,000 may be enough for some purposes.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. Yes i understand what you've done above. But i meant for instance for sample z=4 we have Pr(z=5) = Pr(x=5)Pr(y<5) + Pr(x<5)Pr(y=5) + Pr(x= 5)Pr(y=5) so for this sample one multiplication performed in the third summand + multiplication in other two summands. My question is how many samples multiplication are performed in the other two summands if we assume both X and Y sample space size is equal? if we determined how many multiplications are involved for each sample we simply can calculate the total multiplications. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Enough to exhaust all of the ways the event $P(Z = k)$ can occur. // In the simulation `z = pmax(x,y)` automatically counts all the appropriate simulated values. This makes it easy to check/verify an analytic (albebraic) result without needing to look at all the details. Simulation results can show that analytic result must be wrong and suggest/approximate the correct answer. Sometimes useful in practice, but not a formal mathematical proof.